# convert array of generator to list

Tags: python, networkx

I calculated all shortest paths from a networkx graph using:

```
def steps (node1, node2):
     return nx.all_shortest_paths(G0, node1, node2)

np.vectorize(steps)(df['source'], df['target'])
```

the result is:

```
array([<generator object _build_paths_from_predecessors at 0x7f10b14a4550>,
       <generator object _build_paths_from_predecessors at 0x7f10b14a40d0>,
       <generator object _build_paths_from_predecessors at 0x7f10b14a46d0>,
       <generator object _build_paths_from_predecessors at 0x7f10b14a4750>,
       <generator object _build_paths_from_predecessors at 0x7f10b14a47d0>],
      dtype=object)
```

But I want to have the list of nodes instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
def steps (node1, node2):
     return list(nx.all_shortest_paths(G0, node1, node2))
```

From the documentation of [`all_shortest_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html#all-shortest-paths), it is clear that this function returns a generator, so using a `list` you can consume the generator, extracting all its objects out of it.

Moreover, I think you should modify:

```py
np.vectorize(steps)(df['source'], df['target'])
```

to add the types of the output, as stated in [`np.vectorize` documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```py
np.vectorize(steps, otypes=[object])(df['source'], df['target'])
```

Comment: Yes, it returns a generator and I also used the list(). What I missed is otypes=[object]. Very elegant solution indeed. Thank you!

Comment: BTW: I can't find info about "otypes" but only ctypes. How did you find it?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the link of the documentation where you can find out about `otypes` ;)